# UIPickerView with multiple components / 3rd component items based on component 1 and 2 selection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I just created a UIPickerView with three components. The user selects numbers in wheel 1 and 2 and based on those selections it will show either one of two possible arrays in wheel/component 3. I've got it to work fine with one exception:

Problem:
In order to have the 3rd component updated based on selection of component 1 and 2, the user has to actually physically select an item by moving the picker wheels. But there might be situation in which the user wants to use the default selection (in my case an NSString "0" in component 1 and 2) and does not touch those wheels. Therefore component 3 will not get updated.

Any idea how to address this problem? Is there a way I can update the UIPickerView before the user selects the item in the third component, in order to tricker the default selection in component 1 and 2 as an actual selection without having the user actually move those wheels?

Or lets formulate the question that way: can I have the default row of a UIPickerView automatically selected without selecting the particular row with the finger?

**Additional explanation of what I try to accomplish:**
when the user clicks in a textfield, an UIPickerView with three columns will open up. In the first wheel the user selects a number between 0 and 16, in the second he will select a fraction, and in the third a measuring unit. For example:
1 1/2 cups,
1 ounce,
1/2 cup,
etc.
Based on the number and fraction selection the unit names in the third picker wheel will either be shown in singular or plural spelling (1 cup vs. 2 cups). The whole thing works perfectly as long the first two wheels are touched and a physically selection is done. Problem: lets take for example that the user wants to select "1 ounce". He will move the first wheel to 1, will leave the second alone (as it is already positioned on the 0), and then choose "ounces". But with my code the third wheel will not update to singular spelling. ONLY, if I actually move the second wheel and go back to 0. Then the 3rd wheel instantly changes.

Thanks!!

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    _countPickerData = @[@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11", @"12", @"13", @"14", @"15", @"16"];
        _fractionPickerData = @[@"0", @"1/2", @"1/4", @"1/8", @"3/4", @"3/8", @"5/8", @"7/8"];
        _singularUnitPickerData = @[@"NONE", @"ounce", @"cup", @"pound"];
        _pluralUnitPickerData = @[@"NONE", @"ounces", @"cups", @"pounds"];

// The number of columns of data
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
        return 3;
    }

    // The number of rows of data
    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        switch (component) {
            case 0: return [_countPickerData count];
            case 1: return [_fractionPickerData count];
            case 2:
                 if (([countHelper isEqualToString:@"1"] && [countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"0"]) || ([countHelper isEqualToString:@"0"] && ([countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"1/2" ] || [countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"1/4"] || [countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"1/8"])))
                {
                    return [_singularUnitPickerData count];
                }
                else
                {
                    return [_pluralUnitPickerData count];
                }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    - (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        switch (component)
        {
            case 0: return [_countPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
            case 1: return [_fractionPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
            case 2:
                if (([countHelper isEqualToString:@"1"] && [countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"0"]) || ([countHelper isEqualToString:@"0"] && ([countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"1/2" ] || [countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"1/4"] || [countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"1/8"])))
                {
                    pickedUnitHelper = [_singularUnitPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
                    return pickedUnitHelper;
                }
                else
                {
                    pickedUnitHelper = [_pluralUnitPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
                    return pickedUnitHelper;
                }
            default:break;
        }return nil;
    }

    // Preparing pickerView selection for textFieldIngredientUnit
    NSInteger selectedRowUnit;
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        switch (component)
        {
            case 0:
                countHelper = [_countPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
                return;

            case 1:
                countFractionHelper = [_fractionPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
                return;

            case 2:
                if (([countHelper isEqualToString:@"1"] && [countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"0"]) || ([countHelper isEqualToString:@"0"] && ([countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"1/2" ] || [countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"1/4"] || [countFractionHelper isEqualToString:@"1/8"])))
                {
                    pickedUnitHelper = [_singularUnitPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
                    return;

                }
                else
                {
                    pickedUnitHelper = [_pluralUnitPickerData objectAtIndex:row];
                    return;

                }
            default:break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could change the default selection to "-" instead of "0", that way whatever they choose you'll be able to update the picker.

Comment: I thought of that....but then they could technically choose "-" and what then....?

Comment: Can you also post the code that initializes _countPickerData, _fractionPickerData, _singularUnitPickerData, _pluralUnitPickerData, and countHelper? Kind of hard to tell what's going on without those.

Comment: @mjbn don't let them choose "-", show an error or warning that says they have to pick something. Another option is to set the third component based on the first two when you show the picker.

Comment: @mjbn, what is countHelper?

Comment: countHelper and countFractionHelper are two NSString variables I use to temporarily save the selection in component 0 and 1 of my UIPickerView. I need them to do the conditional statement for my component 2 picker wheel. Based on the selection in the first two wheels either the singular- or the pluralPickerUnit array will be displayed in component 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can automatically select a row of the picker without touching it with your finger. For example:

```
[self.pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:2 animated:YES];
```

Call this before the view appears on the screen. Probably in `viewWillAppear:`

**Update:**

Markus and I checked this out over chat, and I came up with a solution. Basically, any time:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

is called, if it is component 0 or 1, we need to reload component 2. We do this (within the didSelectRow method) by saying:

```
[pickerView reloadComponent:2];
```

There were a couple other minor things in his code that weren't working correctly, but for the purpose of this stack overflow question, this is all that needs to be explained.

Comment: I think that goes in exactly the direction of what I try to accomplish. In my case I need to do [self.unitPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; and [self.unitPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES];   I don't really understand where I have to put that code exactly. I tried in ViewDidLoad but it forces the user to select those rows. whenever I try to change the wheels to something else its jumping back to line 0.

Comment: Well, your code there is selecting row 0, which is the default, so that code won't change anything. Try a different row and see if that changes anything.

Comment: hmmm...thats the thing. row 0 is "0" as a string. and if my user picks "0", I want a different array loaded in component 2. Basically, what I try to do is:  they user picks a number (component 0 and component 2, full numbers and fractions ) and a measuring unit in wheel 2. based on what number/fraction combination he picks, the measuring unit wheel either shows the units in singular or plural spelling. When the user picks "1" in component 0 and "0" in component 1, the measuring units will be shown in singular spelling.Same thing for "0" in component 0 and any fraction in component 1.

Comment: Ok if I'm understanding you correctly, you would need to call [self.pickerView reloadComponent:2] in order to achieve this: "if my user picks '0', I want a different array loaded in component 2". Basically, the picker's strings stay the same until you reload them. Calling [self.pickerView reloadComponent:2] will make the picker update what is in component 2 based on your logic in pickerView:tilteForRow:forComponent:

Comment: Thanks Brian, I gave that a shot. But as long the picker wheel of component 0 or 1 doesn't get moved nothing will be updated in wheel 3. I start to wonder if what I try to accomplish is even possible. At what location in my code should I actually put {self.pickerView reloadComponent:2]?

Comment: Oh trust me, it's possible. You would want to put said code wherever you need the 3rd wheel to be reloaded. My guess would be within your pickerView:didSelectRow:inCompoment: whenever component 0 or 1 is changed.

Comment: nope. I added the code right there and its only changing the content of the 3rd wheel only if I actually turn either the first or second wheel away from "0" and back to "0" (or "1" in the case of the first wheel). But I want the 3rd wheel updated even if one of the wheels is not moved at all.

Comment: Ok let's move this to email - it's getting too long for stack overflow. We can then come back and update the answer when we find it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the very same problem (uipickerview not selecting the first value).  I tried to do..

```
[_myPicker selectRow:0 in Component:0 animated:YES];
```

But that still did not select the value, it turned the picker to whatever I chose in selectRow and Component, but did not send that value anywhere.  So what I did was to create an extra row in my picker's array.  My picker values where 1, 2, 3, and 4.  So when I added the array it looked like this..

```
_myPickerArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@" ", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
```

Now the user must turn the wheel to select something.  In your code you are checking if the input is a string of 1.  If they select the space, then that condition will not be met.  See if that works.